# Trying to overload * operator for matrices

Tags: c++, overloading

so im trying to overload the * operator to make it multiply 2 matrices which are stored in a vector of a vector of int. However, my code seems to always be giving me the wrong output when i input the original matrix:

when i do {0,1,0},{0,2,0},{0,3,0} * {0,2,0},{0,2,0},{0,2,0} the program gives me:

```
0
0
0
0
4
4
0
0
0
0
4
4
0       4       0
0       4       2
0       0       0
```

instead of

```
0 2 0
0 4 0
0 6 0
```

Operator*

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(Matrix m){
    vector<int> mRow;
    vector<int> mCol;
    vector<int> newRow;
    Matrix newM(row, column);

    for(int i =0; i<row-1; j++){
        for(int j = 0; j<row-1; i++){
            mRow = getRow(j);
            mCol = m.getCol(j);
            int r = 0;
            int c = 0;
            int product = 0;
            do{
                product+=mRow[r]*mCol[c];
                ++r;
                ++c;
                cout << product << endl;
            }while(r < row && c < column);          
            newRow.push_back(product);
        }
        newM.setRow(newRow,i);
        newRow.clear(); 
    }
    return newM;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note - consider overloading `operator*=` instead, and implement `operator*` in terms of `operator*=`.

Comment: It's typical to put your logic in the `*=` operator and have `*` operator call it. This is because `*=` can work in-place on the existing matrix whereas `*` results in copies and so is less efficient. I also suggest you take m by const reference to avoid copying it.

Comment: `mRow = getRow(j); mCol = m.getCol(j);` this is copying the whole vector each time. Is that really what you want to do? Why not store it in a reference or pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j<row-1; i++){
//      ^      ^        ^
```

Whoops.

Comment: This is why I always use `k` instead of `j`.

Comment: `j < row - 1` seems suspicious too, perhaps `j < row`.

Comment: @a22asin: Notice how that took me 45 seconds to spot. :)

Comment: (less actually not to brag)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "races" indeed!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes but i have been at this project for 24 hours straight, so im a little tired and missed it.

Comment: @a22asin: No offence intended.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit non taken :)